# What does BodePlot actually calculate?

Tags: plotting, control-systems

I'm using Mathematica v12.3 student edition, running on Windows 10 Home (AMD Ryzen 5 4500U with Radeon Graphics 2.38 GHz).

I'm trying to get a Bode plot of an example function. I try to do it with the `BodePlot` function, to compare it with the result I obtained "directly" (meaning by calculating `20*Log10[Abs[..]]` and plotting the results with `LogLinearPlot`).

```
function = TransferFunctionModel[1000/(1 + s/10), s];
functionF[f_] := 1000/(1 + (2 Pi I f)/10)

Show[BodePlot[function[I 2 Pi f], {f, 0.1, 10}, PlotStyle -> Red, 
GridLines -> Automatic, FrameStyle -> Black, 
FrameLabel -> {{"Frequenza [Hz]", 
   "Guadagno [dB]"}, {"Frequenza [Hz]", "Fase[\[Degree]]"}}, 
ImageSize -> Large][[1]][[1]],LogLinearPlot[20 *Log10[Abs[functionF[f]]], {f, 0.1, 10},PlotStyle -> Green, GridLines -> Automatic, FrameStyle -> Black, FrameLabel -> {{"Frequenza [rad Hz]", 
 "Guadagno [dB]"}, {"Frequenza [rad Hz]", "Fase[\[Degree]]"}}, ImageSize -> Large]]
```

[image: comparison between the output of BodePlot and the manual calculation]

The two graphs displayed above are different; I'm pretty sure, though, that what is being calculated with `BodePlot` (the magnitude graph) is `20*Log10 [Abs[ ...something]]`.

What am I missing?

Comment: Added control-systems tag.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your understanding of what [`BodePlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BodePlot.html) (with the default `ScalingFunctions->{Automatic,"dB"}`) computes is correct.

However, unfortunately, it 'hijacks' the [`Ticks`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Ticks.html) attribute of plot-related functions to display it with the x-axis you see. As such, when you combine it with [`LogLinearPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LogLinearPlot.html) which itself uses a transformation function for its axes - they don't line up.

Here's a workaround/demonstration these are indeed identical by extracting the points from [`BodePlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BodePlot.html):

```
functionF[f_] := 1000/(1 + (2 Pi I f)/10)
functionDB[f_] := 20 Log10[Abs[functionF[f]]]

bodePlot = BodePlot[functionF[f], {f, 0.1, 10}, PlotLayout -> "Magnitude"];
extractedBodePoints = Cases[bodePlot, Line[pts__] :> pts, Infinity][[1]];
extractedBodePoints = MapAt[10^# &, extractedBodePoints, {All, 1}];

equallySpacedFrequencyPoints = Power[10., Subdivide[-1, 1, 100]];
manualPoints = Thread[{equallySpacedFrequencyPoints,functionDB /@ equallySpacedFrequencyPoints}];

ListLogLinearPlot[{extractedBodePoints, manualPoints}, Joined -> True,PlotStyle -> {Red, Directive[Blue, Dashed]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Ah, all clear. Thank you so much!